# Using :not and :hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to add a hover effect to all list elements that don't have a class of "active" which I cannot figure out how. I can change it's normal style through the following:

```
li:not(.active){
padding-bottom:5px;
border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
```

Which works just fine, but I can't seem to get it working for the hover state.
I have tried `li:not:hover (.active){` and others and it doesn't work for me.
Any css-only solutions, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try  li:not(.active):hover ?

Comment: Wow, I did. I apparently had a space in between the closing parenthesis and the colon.

Comment: Using `ul li:not(.active):hover` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8TEy8/

Comment: Thanks, this was my first time using multiple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to separate `:not()` from its argument! Use either `li:hover:not(.active)` or `li:not(.active):hover`.